# Setup modem to go through an external proxy server

Tags: router, proxy, modem

I know this can be done on PC, but when there are more than 30 devices at home, I want to setup this in the modem/router.

I only require the HTTP traffics to go through an external proxy server.

How do you do this? Is this by default available in any $50 modem/router? If not, which specific brand/model has this function?

Simply answer no if there is no such product in the market and I will quietly setup proxies for my 30+ devices one by one.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done exactly this [using the DD-WRT firmware](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/HTTPRedirect), it might be possible with others as well. I would expect you could find a DD-WRT compatible router for USD 50.

Cheers,